# nodejs can't find my own module realted to parent path

Tags: node.js, fs

I have a tree like this.

```
folder1
    file1.js
folder2
    file2.js
index.js
```

I require my file1 from withing index.js

from file 1 i want to require file2

if I do `const file2= require('../folder2/file2.js');` it works

if I do it dynamically so

```
const myFiles = fs.readdirSync('../folder2').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of myFiles ) 
{
    const myFile = require(`../folder2/${file}`);
}
```

I got this

```
 return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), options.encoding);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'displaying a wrong path here'
```

If in my readdir i do a simple `./`

I still got

```
Cannot find module './folder2/file2.js'
```

I really don't understand that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fs` is unaware of current module path and relies on current working directory (`process.cwd()`) for relative paths.

For actions that are specific to current module path, `__dirname` should be used:

```
fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, '../folder2'))
```

Comment: Ok, I used what you say and it return this :
D:\Users\username\Documents\git\projectDirectory\

so technically, if I do ./folder2/file2.js it should work, but it doesn't

Comment: Technically, `.` is not what you think. As I said, `fs` relies on *current working directory*. `process.cwd() === __dirname` inside `folder1/file1` only if you started the script from `folder1`.